# Put the list of values into separate textbox using C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am having a value `["aaa","bbb","ccc"]` in column. I have to put each value in separate textbox without double quotes.

I have tried (in view):

```
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => (m.editPeriodicTask.args[0]), new { @id = "args0", @class = "form-control-list" })</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => (m.editPeriodicTask.args[1]), new { @id = "args1", @class = "form-control-list" })</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => (m.editPeriodicTask.args[2]), new { @id = "args2", @class = "form-control-list" })</td>
```

and also

```
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => (m.editPeriodicTask.args.split(',')[0]), new { @id = "args0", @class = "form-control-list" })</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => (m.editPeriodicTask.args.split(',')[1]), new { @id = "args1", @class = "form-control-list" })</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => (m.editPeriodicTask.args.split(',')[2]), new { @id = "args2", @class = "form-control-list" })</td>
```

but it does not gives the exact solution what i need.
How to do this.?

Comment: Use a view model with a property `string[]` and convert your value to an array using the `string.Split()` method and then use a `for` loop to generate a textbox for each value in the array (side note: you usage of `@id = "args"` is generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html)

Comment: Isn't the value already a string array?

Comment: @EthanFischer, Maybe/maybe not. OP has stated the value is in a 'column' which suggests its not

Comment: Not sure why you have accepted the answer you did. It would never bind to your model when your submit the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also do this, like the below code

```
    var value = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"];
    var data1 = value.Replace("[","").Replace("]","");
    var item = data1.Split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
    {
        var data = item[i].Replace("\"","");
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.editPeriodicTask.args, new { @id = "args" + i, @class = "form-control-list", @Value =  data})</td>
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Actually the 'args' only having the ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]. By doing this too also not giving the result which i am expect

Comment: I am facing an error in replace statement. could you please check this @anand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103578/discussion-between-sara-and-anand).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@{ 
     foreach (var value in Model.editPeriodicTask.args.ToList().Split(','))
     {
         <td> @Html.TextBox("name", value, new {@id = "args", @class = "form-control-list"}) </td>
     }
}
```

Comment: '@id = "args" will generate the same id for each textbox right? Should she use @class = "args"?'

Comment: Yes I know it will generate same ids but she has done the same in her question so I just used that.

Comment: @ Akshay, i have got the same output as mine. The first textbox having ["aaa" 2nd textbox having "bbb" and the third having "ccc"]. I have to remove the [ and "" in the textbox result

Comment: @sara, you can replace "[" before setting the value

Answer (score 0):

Try this( get a counter used in differentiating the ids before you loop to create the textboxex )

```
 @{int count = 0;}

 @foreach (var value in Model.editPeriodicTask.args.ToList().Split(','))
 {
    <td> @Html.TextBox("name", value, new {@id = "args"+count, @class = "form-control-list"}) </td>

count++
 }
```

Comment: Okay but how to use the different id name in controller